# Tkinter not acting the same on OSX as windows and possibly Linux

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, keycode

I am building a simple input module for a robot I am building (the robot is running off a pi so it will be ruining in Linux).  I started working on the code on a windows laptop and when I got home I took it over to my mac as it has a much bigger screen to work with. When I did this I noticed that Tkinter behaves differently.

For starters it returns a different keycode.  On Windows the keycode for enter is 13 yet on the mac it is returned as 2359309

On top of that on the windows computer when I press a key my shell will print Key pressed keycode and wont print Key released until I release the key
On the mac however if I hold the key down it keeps saying pressing key keycode releasing key keycode over and over again even if i do not release the key.

Is there a way that I can fix this?

Here is my code for the module

```
from tkinter import *
dictOfKeyButtons = dict()
history = []

class ButtonsKey(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.isDown = False
        self.isUp = True

    def Pressed(self):
        self.isDown = True
        self.isUp = False
        print("Key pressed: ", self.name)

    def Released(self):
        self.isDown = True
        self.isUp = False
        print("Key released: ", self.name)

def checkForKey(theKeyCode):
    if not theKeyCode in dictOfKeyButtons:
        dictOfKeyButtons[theKeyCode] = ButtonsKey(theKeyCode)

def getKeyDown(theKeyCode):
    checkForKey(theKeyCode)
    isDown = dictOfKeyButtons[theKeyCode].isDown
    return isDown

def getKeyUp(theKeyCode):
    checkForKey(theKeyCode)
    isUp = dictOfKeyButtons[theKeyCode].isUp
    return isUp 

def keyup(e):

    checkForKey(e.keycode)

    if  e.keycode in history :
        history.pop(history.index(e.keycode))

        var.set(str(history))
        dictOfKeyButtons[e.keycode].Released()

def keydown(e):

    checkForKey(e.keycode)

    if not e.keycode in history :
        history.append(e.keycode)

        var.set(str(history))
        print("i")
        dictOfKeyButtons[e.keycode].Pressed()
    else:
        #may do something with holding key down here
        pass

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
a_label = Label(root,textvariable = var ).pack()

frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

I will be using  if input.getKeyDown(keycode): which runs in a update method that gets called by a tick if you are wondering how I plan to use this module. This will allow me to do things that tkinker by it self cant do.

Comment: Does autorepeat happen for all keys, including, for instance, Shift?  There may be a difference in system settings, or a mandatory difference on Mac.  The Mac keycode is really odd.  You need to determine the behavior on your target system.  For development, import sys.platform and condition your code on the result.

Comment: What do you mean by condition my code on the result? change how it runs depending on the OS? I would do that but I don't know how I would be able to make tinker to run on the mac like it dose on windows.

Comment: If keycodes depend on the system, there is easy to customize.  I can't say more about autorepeat without a Mac system to play with.